# what is the best practice to handle carriage returns when exporting data from pandas dataframe to CSV?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-formats

While trying to export data from a pandas dataframe to a CSV, we noticed that carriage returns (inserted at the middle of a line or at the end of a line) produce outputs that are different from newlines. In particular, strings that are usually embraced by quotes in the standard CSV output, when the string contains a \n, do not receive the quotes anymore if a carriage return (\r) is placed. What is the standard practice to deal with \n and \r when exporting from a pandas dataframe to CSV and when importing from a CSV to a dataframe?  Is there a special way to set line terminators that accommodate the differences between \n and \r?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,"Hi\rHello"], [2, "example"]], 
                  columns = ["id", "msg"])

df.to_csv("df.csv", index = False)
```

The above example produces an output without quotes.  This is a problem when reading the CSV, as we will have a new line in the file that will be treated as a new observation to be treated independently of the previous lines.  The example below produces an outpupt with quotes, that does not cause this problem.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,"Hi\rHello"], [2, "example"]], 
                  columns = ["id", "msg"])

df.to_csv("df.csv", index = False)
```